# Maven giving compilation error while compiling old legacy collections code

Tags: java, maven

In my application, there is old collection code which is written without generics.

So when ever there is code like

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

maven is throwing following error - Missing type argument for Generic class List.

Same code is getting compiled fine in the eclipse.

How I can get build done for same code using maven?

Thanks

Comment: So your source code is Java 1.4 compatible, and want to the source code to be compiled into Java 1.7 byte code. Right?

Comment: Interesting. How is your `maven-compiler-plugin` configured? This message should be a warning, not a build-failing error.

Comment: @Harry.Chen : yes. I am trying to create build for java 1.6 as of now.

Comment: @Slanec : thanks for the pointer. changed configuration of my maven-compiler-plugin and now i am able to build.

Comment: Answer credit goes to @Slanec

Answer (score 1):

You can set the source code compatibility level by config the maven-compiler-plugin. An example is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.4</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```